# Why __import__() is returning the package instead of the module?

Tags: python, module, package, python-import

I have this file structure (where the dot is my working directory):

```
.
+-- testpack
     +-- __init__.py
     +-- testmod.py
```

If I load the `testmod` module with the `import` statement, I can call a function that is declared within:

```
>>> import testpack.testmod
>>> testpack.testmod.testfun()
hello
```

but if I try to do the same using the `__import__()` function, it doesn't work:

```
>>> __import__("testpack.testmod").testfun()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    __import__("testpack.testmod").testfun()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'testfun'
```

indeed, it returns the package `testpack` instead of the module `testmod`:

```
>>> __import__("testpack.testmod").testmod.testfun()
hello
```

How come?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but note that Python 3.1+ has better ways to do dynamic imports: [importlib](http://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html).

Comment: @delnan: it's available in 2.7 too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour is given in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__):

> When the name variable is of the form package.module, normally, the
>   top-level package (the name up till the first dot) is returned, not
>   the module named by name. However, when a non-empty fromlist argument
>   is given, the module named by name is returned.

...

> The statement import spam.ham results in this call:
>
> `spam = __import__('spam.ham', globals(), locals(), [], -1)`
>
> Note how `__import__()` returns the toplevel module here because this is
>   the object that is bound to a name by the import statement.

Also note the warning at the top:

> This is an advanced function that is not needed in everyday Python
>   programming, unlike `importlib.import_module()`.

And then later:

> If you simply want to import a module (potentially within a package)
>   by name, use `importlib.import_module()`.

So the solution here is to use [`importlib.import_module()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module).

It's worth noting that the double underscores either side of a name in Python imply that the object at hand isn't meant to be used directly most of the time. Just as you should generally use `len(x)` over `x.__len__()` or `vars(x)`/`dir(x)` over `x.__dict__`. Unless you know why you need to use it, it's generally a sign something is wrong.